# Pyomo/CBC: Get last iteration of CBC optimizer before infeasible

Tags: pyomo, coin-or-cbc

I'm migrating an optimization script (using Pyomo and CBC) from a local Windows 10 machine to a Linux-based platform (Dataiku). For some reason either pyomo or cbc behaves differently even though there have been no changes to the optimization part of the script. On local Windows, even though the optimization was infeasible, I got a last-iteration solution before it turned out to be infeasible - for our purposes this was good enough, since the infeasibility appears in unimportant places and as there are about 100k variables, it did not make sense to look for them. On the linux-based platform, when the solution is infeasible, I get the output of initial values, basically zeros on all non-fixed positions. I assumed that this would be fixed by turning off the presolve, but it still returns initial values. Does anyone know, how to get the last iteration of the optimizer?
Thanks

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that (a) the solver will return a result with some pedigree like "best possible" or some quality if the problem is infeasible and that (b) the infeasibility is in some way controllable to "unimportant places".  AFAIK, *neither of those statements are true.*  I've seen complete gibberish come out for infeasible models.  Why don't you fix the model and make it more elastic or such to remove the infeasibility?  Relying on anything that comes out of the solve when infeasibility is declared seems like crazy talk.

Comment: Thanks, that helps, I won't pretend to understand the inner workings of the optimizer, yeah, I did assume, that it comes out as some sort of best possible, since almost all of the output checks satisfied the conditions to within 1% margin. Anyway, I'd still like to understand why it behaves differently on Windows vs. Linux machines if anyone knows.